# How to import/add libraries into Spring STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am having an issue with Spring STS.  I'm receiving the following messages:

This one when trying to download the template projects:

> "Error while downloading or parsing descriptors file
>   'https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml':
>
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while retrieving
>   https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml"

...and this one when I check for updates:

> "Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail. No
>   repository found at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/site.xml. No
>   repository found at http://geronimo.apache.org/devtools/. Unable to
>   read repository at
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException"

also, see the attachment for a screen shoot of how the tool suite will not import java.whatever and/or org.springframework.whatever

I believe that all three of these issues are related however, I can't prove or fix it.

[image: Import errors]
[image: github - download template error]
[image: google, eclipse and geronimo - update error]

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible things to be checked in here, 
 1. Are you under some kind of proxy? 
 2. Did you download Spring STS directly or updated eclipse? 
 3. If your Spring STS is not working properly, you can download latest [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and use this [link](http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2/) as update site. 
 4. You can check your project classpath also to just cross confirm that you are not missing anything up there.

HTH

Comment: 1.)We do have a proxy however, the exclusion list is a list of internal sites (i.e. do not send these IPs through the proxy) - is that the issue? I dunno... I've gone into "network connections" switched to manual or direct and added the proxy info into http, https and socks - non of that worked....please help me explore the proxy issus further, if needed...

Comment: 3.) may try to go that rought - however, why did I also have an issue when trying to download the repository at dl-ssl.google ???